# load event not firing in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to do a business logic on a map whenever some events are done by a user.

> I'm able to get working *drag* , *dblclick* and *zoomstart* events.

**But load event is not getting fired for me. (On Browser load initially)**

My sample code below :

```
  var map = L.map('map').setView([34.7320,-86.5966], 14);

  map.on('load drag dblclick zoomstart', function() {      
         // My business logic goes here.
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done when you call setView, that makes the map fire the load event.

```
var map = L.map('map').on('load', function(){
  // Your business logic here...
}).setView([34.7320,-86.5966], 14);
```

(OR)

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3560

http://jsfiddle.net/QUGyr/1/

Answer (score 3):

Use `map.whenReady(fn)` if you just want to do something when the map is ready:

```
map.whenReady(function(){
    console.log('Map Loaded!');
});
```

Longer explanation:
I'm having the same issue (with LeafletJS 1.6 and 1.7.1) with 'idle' and 'load' not triggering unless I define it before setting setView.

Digging through the source I discovered there's also `map.whenReady(function(){});` which is working for me and also works if the map is already loaded.

So instead of:

```
map.on('load', function(){
    console.log('Map Loaded!');
});
```

Use:

```
map.whenReady(function(){
    console.log('Map Loaded!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=de) you can use the event

> 'idle'

instead of

> 'load'

Comment: No luck :( @Unlockedluca